# How to fetch Key Vault Secret value and override Global Parameter of ADF in Azure DevOps Pipeline?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I have value of URL in Key Vault.
I have global parameter URL in Azure Data Factory. (URL for Dev, Test, Prod)
How to fetch Key Vault URL value to global parameters so that I can deploy different URL for each environments?

```
1) ADF->Manage->Global Parameters->New "URL" string "http://www.dev.com"
2) ADF->Pipelines->Web Activity-> URL set as "@pipeline().globalParameters.URL"
3) ADF->Publish
4) Azure DevOps->Repos->factory->my-warehouse-dev-df.json
```

my-warehouse-dev-df.json

```
 "properties": {
        "globalParameters": {
            "URL": {
                "type": "string",
                "value": "http://www.dev.com"
            }
        }
    },
```

5. Azure DevOps->Releases->Added "Azure Key Vault" Job

   - Azure Powershell: Pre Deployment
   - Azure Key Vault
   - ARM Template deployment: Data Factory
   - Azure Powershell: Post Deployment
6. How do I get secret value and overwrite globalParameters with Key Vault value in Azure DevOps Pipeline Release?

   - Dev env URL = "http://www.dev.com"
   - UAT env URL = "http://www.uat.com"
   - PROD env URL = "http://www.prod.com"

Answer (score 0):

You can parameterize your global parameter of ARM template in DevOps and pass desired value to it depending on environment in which you are deploying.

Kindly check below article which explains using Azure Key vault secrets in Azure Pipelines.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops